# Setting The Date with Jcalendar

Tags: java, calendar, jcalendar

I have used JCalender to get the date. It returned the date like this

Thu Mar 01 18:35:53 PST 2012

But what I need is this format.

2012 Sep 04

Here is the code I am using:

```
java.util.Date s = txt_dob.getDate();
```

Comment: It looks like there are multiple JCalendar libraries - which one are you using, and what have you tried?

Comment: `code`java.util.Date s = txt_dob.getDate();`code`

Comment: String s =   ((JTextField)txt_dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, even though the snippet of code you gave us doesn't really give any indication of effort into solving the problem yourself, or tell us which `JCalendar` library you're using, I think I can guess what's wrong.

You're probably just calling `toString()` (possibly implicitly) on a `java.util.Date`. Don't do that - it will always assume the local time zone, and a default format based on the system locale.

Instead, use `SimpleDateFormat` - and remember to set the time zone appropriately, and potentially the locale. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String text = formatter.format(txt_dob.getDate());
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or other Implementations of [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to format your Date-Strings as needed

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution!!!!!!!!!!!! :) :)

```
String s = ((JTextField)txt_dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

Comment: You never even asked a proper question, which makes it pretty hard to understand what the "solution" is really about. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before you ask your next question.